# Are both "in regards to" and "regarding to" correct?

Tags: word-choice, writing

Do *in regards to* and *regarding to* imply different meanings or is it okay to use them interchangeably?

Example:

> This mail is in regards to your inquiry.
>   This mail is regarding to your inquiry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say these are correct:

> This mail is in regards to your inquiry.
>
> This mail is regarding your inquiry.

I honestly have never seen this use:

> This mail is regarding to your inquiry.

Comment: In the UK the first example is more commonly written, "This mail is with regard to you inquiry".

Comment: Is your 3rd example's grammatically correct?

Comment: When I write _in regards to_, the spell checker suggests me _in regard to_, or to try with _about_ or _concerning_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno technically, "in regards to" is improper, but it is such a common error that most people probably don't even realize that it **is** an error.  See John M. Landsberg's answer below.

Comment: I doubt 'This mail is in regards to your inquiry.' is correct. 'In regards to' is usually considered as an error, as stated below. See https://writingexplained.org/in-regard-to-vs-in-regards-to and/or https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2021/10/in-regard-to-vs-in-regards-to.html

Answer (score 11):

"In regards to" is a common error, but an error nonetheless. "In regard to" is correct. The "s" would be stuck onto "regard" only if you are saying "as regards," which is a correct alternative.

"With regard to" is also correct.

"Regarding to" is incorrect; "regarding" is all you need to say.

Comment: It's only incorrect if you are being prescriptive about. V. http://grammarist.com/usage/regard-regards/

Answer (score 0):

The "auto-correct" is correcting you becuase "in regards to" is grammatically incorrect. The word "regards" should only be utilized in the sense of sending one's regards. For example,   "-I'm flying to Florida to see my family tomorrow"
"-Oh, send them my regards"

However in the sense of "pertaining to," the correct word is "regard" and the correct phrase is "in regard to" (without an "s")